# How can I do to avoid to put " "?

Tags: javascript

Hello I have this variable in my code :

```
var text = text1 + " " + text2
```

But I would like to know if there is a better way in order to avoid to use " " for a space using Javascript. I thought like a function but I can't find these kind of functions...

Could you help me please ?

Thank you !

Comment: This is probably the simplest way to separate two words. Why do you want to avoid it?

Comment: `I thought like a function but I can't find these kind of functions` write one .. something like `function joinWithSpace(...args) { return args.join(' '); }` ... then `var text = joinWithSpace(text1, text2)` ... but, are you really making the code better like this?

Comment: "*But I would like to know if there is a better way*" what are your parameters for "better"?

Comment: you can use single quote `' '`

Answer (score 3):

You can try [`Template Literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

> Template literals are string literals allowing ***embedded expressions***. You can use multi-line strings and string interpolation features with them. They were called "template strings" in prior editions of the ***ES2015*** specification.

```js
var text1 = 'Some Text',
text2 = 'Some Other Text';
var text = `${text1} ${text2}`;
console.log(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ES6 strings, like this :

```
var text = `${text1} ${text2}`;
```